# Is carbon dioxide soluble in petroleum ether, and why?

Tags: solubility

I googled it, and I'm finding some forum posts that say no, but no authoritative reference.
CO2 is somewhat soluble in water (1.7 g/L at 20°C) and I understand that it's mostly NOT because it forms carbonic acid: it's just dissolved CO2 molecules. Why wouldn't the same thing happen in petroleum ether?
Has anyone tried putting petroleum ether in a SodaStream device?

Comment: Carbon dioxide is a dipole so it would made perfect sense to be soluble in water.Petroleum ether is again a polar molecule so why not?

Comment: mm petroleum ether is not polar is made of aliphatic compounds and carbon dioxide has dipole 0

Comment: While most of CO2 absorbed by water stays this way, the reaction is still driving the dissolution equilibrium forward, especially in high pH.

Comment: Carbone dioxide has zero dipole, but it's 2 bonds do not. They are polar and attracted to water. Dissociation of carbonic acid plays very minor role here.

Comment: @Mithoron ..but not for low pH of water with  dissolved CO2. 1 atm CO2 leads to pH cca 3.9, the true pKa1 of H2CO3 is 3.6, so bicarbonates makes just few  0.x% of total CO2 content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carbon dioxide is, in fact, **more soluble in nonpolar solvents than in water**.

From the [Wikipedia page on carbon dioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide): Solubility in water
**1.45 g/L** at 25 °C (77 °F), 100 kPa
(Alternative source: [CRC handbook](https://sites.chem.colostate.edu/diverdi/all_courses/CRC%20reference%20data/solubility%20of%20carbon%20dioxide%20in%20water.pdf). Solubility is about twice as much at 0°C.)

From [IUPAC, Solubility Data Series: Carbon Dioxide in Non-Aqueous Solvents at Pressures Less Than 200 kPa](https://srdata.nist.gov/solubility/IUPAC/SDS-50/SDS-50.pdf), chart on page 3: mole fraction of CO<sub>2</sub> in hexane at 101.3 kPa, 300 K = **0.012**, which corresponds to 4 g/L.
(Solubility is only slightly (10-20%) higher at 0°C.)

So the forum posts I read were wrong.

As to why, I suppose it's sufficient to argue that CO<sub>2</sub> is a nonpolar molecule, and like dissolves like.

(It's true because it's Latin: *Similia similibus solvuntur!* )

Comment: Nitrogen is non polar molecule as well, and that is the reason it's solubility in water is 2 orders lower than for CO2  :-)

Comment: It is rather the CO2 bond polarity does not manifest in non polar solvents, where the dominance has zero dipole moment. Similis similibus solvuntur as Well. :-)

Answer (score -1):

While $\ce{CO2}$  as a symmetric molecule has  zero dipole moment, its 2 $\ce{C=O}$ bands do have dipole moment and are polar.

Polar water molecules interact with the polar bonds what decreases   $\ce{CO2(aq)}$ chemical potential and raises solubility of $\ce{CO2}$ some 2 orders above solubility of $\ce{O2}$ or $\ce{N2}$.

That does not happen in non polar solvents likes alkanes of petroether.

BTW, why would anybody put petroether in a soda stream ??

Comment: I'd like you to put petroleum ether in a Sodastream so you could tell me if you get fizzy petroleum ether of course! (It goes without saying that I won't do it myself.)

Comment: On a more serious note, do you have any actual data on the solubility of carbon dioxide in petroleum ether? Or maybe hexane?

Comment: This is behind a paywall  https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/je0602972

Comment: That's cool but the lowest pressure they consider is 17 bar - I'd like to know about atmospheric pressure.

Comment: @Martin   ..proportionality.... 1/17 of 17 bar

Comment: It's not that simple. Dissolved CO2 vs. pressure is not linear at those pressures.